# React and axios - sending GET and POST requests instead of only POST

Tags: reactjs, request, axios

In React I have this form being submitted:

```
<form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmitOrder(event) }>
          <div className="field">
             <input
                name="client"
                className="input is-dark is-large"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Client name"
                required
                //value={this.state.formClient.client}
                onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
              /> 
          </div>
            <div className="field">
              <input
                name="email"
                className="input is-dark is-large"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Client email"
                required
                //value={this.state.formClient.email}
                onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
              />
            </div>
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="button is-dark is-large is-fullwidth"
            value="Submit"
          />
          </form>
```

This is `handleSubmitOrder()`, handling a `POST` request:

```
  handleSubmitOrder(event) {
    const {userId} = this.props
    const data = {
      client: this.state.formClient.client,
      email: this.state.formClient.email,
    };
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/orders/${userId}`;
    axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  };
```

I use `nginx` as proxy server (nginx.conf):

```
  location /orders {
    proxy_pass        http://web:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

and at my Flask server, I have my view, specifically declaring `POST` method only:

```
@orders_bp.route('/orders/<user_id>', methods=['POST'])
def orders(user_id):
    # business logic
    return jsonify(response_object), 200
```

This endpoint is being reached alright, and logic at `/orders` is being successfully processed.

But when I submit the form, I'm getting a `404` error at browser, and, to my confusion, a GET request:

```
"GET /orders?client=Ozorio&email=ozo%40gmail.com&phone=118888888&select=pick HTTP/1.0" 404 -
```

In case it helps, I also have url declared here:

**App.jsx:**

```
<Route exact path='/orders' render={() => (
   <Orders
     formType={'Orders'}
     isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
    />
)} />
```

and here at navbar, where I ask for the url:

```
    {props.isAuthenticated &&
   <Link to="/orders" className="navbar-item">Orders</Link>
    }
```

note: I am authenticated.

---

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way forms behave by default is rather interesting. You can read more about it [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-fs-action)

At the end of the day you need to add

`event.preventDefault()`

at the top of you `handleSubmitOrder` function (to prevent the default behavior of submitting a form)